# how to go the middle of the singularly linked list in one iteration?

Tags: java, data-structures

Recently I have been asked one question that in a singularly linked list how do we go to the middle of the list in one iteration.

```
A --> B --> C --> D (even nodes)
```

for this it should return address which points to B

```
A --> B --> C (odd nodes)
```

for this also it should return address which points to B

There is one solution of taking two pointers one moves one time and other moves two times but it does not seem working here

```
LinkedList p1,p2;

while(p2.next != null)
{
    p1 = p1.next;
    p2 = p2.next.next;

}

System.out.print("middle of the node" + p1.data); //This does not give accurate result in odd and even
```

Please help if anyone has did this before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't advance p1 unless you *successfully* advanced p2 twice; otherwise, with a list length of 2 you end up with both pointing at the end (and you indicated even length lists should round toward the beginning).

So:

```
while ( p2.next != null ) {
    p2 = p2.next;
    if (p2.next != null) {
        p2 = p2.next;
        p1 = p1.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is what I written but just 14 min before you wrote it :)

Comment: @org.life.java: I read your answer and couldn't tell if your step 2 meant the right thing or not; code is not as ambiguous as English.

Comment: I think picture is  not as ambiguous as Code :) anyways

Answer (score 6):

The basic algorithm would be

**0** Take two pointers

**1** Make both pointing to first node

**2** Increment first with two node and first if its successful then traverse second to one node ahead

**3** when second reaches end first one would be at middle.

**Update:**

It will definitely work in **odd** case, for even case you need to check one more condition if first point is allowed to move *next* but not *next to next* then both pointers will be at middle you need to decide which to take as middle

[image]

Comment: it does not happen in both case odd and even thats why I mentioned odd and even case

Answer (score 1):

I know you've already accepted an answer, but this whole question sounds like an exercise in cleverness rather than an attempt to get the correct solution.  Why would you do something in O(n) when you can do it in O(n/2)?

EDIT: This used to assert O(1) performance, and that is simply not correct.  Thanks to ysth for pointing that out.

In practice, you would do this in zero iterations:

```
LinkedList list = ...
int size = list.size();
int middle = (size / 2) + (size % 2 == 0 ? 0 : 1) - 1; //index of middle item
Object o = list.get(middle);  //or ListIterator it = list.listIterator(middle);
```

Comment: If that's O(1), your LinkedList isn't a linked list.

Comment: @ysth Woops! You are right.  Java's implementation of get(index) does iterate; but it converges toward the center.  Still, O(n/2) is faster than O(n).

Comment: For that your list implementation must assure that there is a field with current size always set. Otherwise, the only way to get the size would be to count all the elements, which is O(n)

Comment: @Jeff - we know what you are trying to say, but it is an abuse of "big O" notation.  `O(N)` and `O(N/2)` mean the same thing according to the mathematical definition.

Comment: @Goran Jovic Java's LinkedList implementation does keep track of its size.

Comment: @Stephen C - Yes, I knew I was pushing things there... ;)

Comment: @Jeff: I know. Your solution is correct. I just pointed out to the precondition that it must meet in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of taking two pointers and one moves a half the rate should work fine.  Most likely it is not the solution but your actual implementation that is the problem.  Post more details of your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
static ListElement findMiddle(ListElement head){
    ListElement slower = head;
    ListElement faster = head;
    while(faster.next != null && faster.next.next !=null ){
        faster = faster.next.next;
        slower = slower.next;
    } 
    return slower;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Node middle(Node head){

    Node slow=head,fast=head;
    while(fast!=null& fast.next!=null && fast.next.next!=null){

         slow=slow.next;
         fast=fast.next.next;                   
    } 


    if(fast!=null && fast.next!=null){
        slow=slow.next;
    }


    return slow;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ListNode middleNode(ListNode head) {
    if(head == null) return head;

    ListNode slow = head;
    ListNode fast = head;
    while(fast != null && fast.next != null) {
        fast = fast.next.next;
        slow = slow.next;
    }

    return slow;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.