# How to find a middle value or node from linked list in java?

Tags: java, linked-list

I have the 50 values in linked list.how to find a middle value or node of linked list?

```
List list = new LinkedList();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    list.add(String.valueOf(i));
}

int size = list.size();
int middle = (size / 2);
System.out.println(list.get(middle).toString());...
```

i got an answer like this....
But my team leader said to find in another way? 
Is there any other built in method to iterate in linked list?i tried ...but i dint get any built in method for finding middle value...And
or can u any one suggest another logic to find the value of middle node in linke list?

thank you.......

Comment: One problem with your approach is that if the size of your list is an odd number, you will not get the middle node. Example: If the size is 3, your middle node would be 1. fixing it is like int middle = size/2+size%2. But i don't think this is what your team leader was referring to.

Comment: sorry..watever u said ok..but wat my team leader said na,have to try to find another logic without dividing,modulas the size...is there?

Comment: Question isn't clear what the "middle" is when the list length is even.

Comment: This is bizarre, why would you not simply use list.size() to determine the middle? It's not going to make any difference to the speed or complexity of your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Get 2 references to the same list.

```
In a single loop:
Advance the 1st list 2 nodes at a time.
Advance the 2nd list 1 node at a time.
Loop until the 1st loop reaches the end.
```

Comment: sorry i dint get u?..if u dnt mind can u pls explain still more briefly?

Comment: You can see [another similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509215/how-to-go-the-middle-of-the-singularly-linked-list-in-one-iteration). You have the pseudo-code from my answer, you should implement it on your own.

Answer (score 1):

```
List list = new LinkedList();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    list.add(String.valueOf(i));
}

int end = list.size() - 1;
int start = 0;
while (start > end) {
    start++;
    end--;
}
if(start == end) //The arrays length is an odd number and you found the middle
    return start;
else //The arrays length is an even number and there really isn't a middle
    //Do something else here because you have an even number
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your team lead was suggesting you use an ArrayList rather than a LinkedList.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(50);
```