# Finding middle of double linked list for even number of nodes

Tags: java, list

Following is my code to find middle node of double linked list but it works only for odd number of nodes. i cannot figure out how to take care of case of even number of nodes:

```
public Object findMiddleNode() {
    DLNode first = getHeadNode();
    DLNode last = getTailNode();
    while(first!=last) {
        first = first.getNext();
        last = last.getPrevious();
    }
    return first.getElement();      
}
```

---

this is my updated code:

```
public MyDequeue findMiddleNode() {
    DLNode first = getHeadNode();
    DLNode last = getTailNode();
    MyDequeue m = new MyDequeue();
    while(first!=last && first.getNext()!= last) {
        first = first.getNext();
        last = last.getPrevious();
    }
    if(first == last) {
        m.insertLast(first.getElement());           
        return m;
    }           
    else {
        m.insertLast(first.getElement());
        m.insertLast(last.getElement());
        return m;
    }
}
```

the class MyDequeue is my implementation of a doubly linked list. the reason I returned MyDequeue is because I already had a static print method that prints the elements of a doubly linked list.

Comment: If there are an even number of nodes, which node is the middle?  The "middle" is two nodes, presumably.

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150843/how-to-find-a-middle-value-or-node-from-linked-list-in-java

Comment: i saw this link but it doesnt expalin for even number of noes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an even number of nodes, first and last pass each other at the middle. For example, if you have 4 nodes 1..4, first will be 2 when last is 3. At the next iteration, first will be 3, and last will be 2. So you never fail the while loop test (first != last) needed to exit the loop at the proper point. A simple fix is to modify your while test to be

`while ((first != last) && (first.getNext() != last)) {`.

Comment: shudnt it be while ((first != last) || (first.getNext() != last)) {
i dont think both will be true at same time.

Answer (score 1):

```
This is my code in java 
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class DeleteMiddleLinkedList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
        list.add("1");
        list.add("2");
        list.add("3");
        list.add("4");
        list.add("5");

        DeleteMiddleLinkedList ds = new DeleteMiddleLinkedList();
        ds.middleDelete(list, "");

        for (String s : list) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

    }

    public void middleDelete(LinkedList<String> list, String s) {
        int size = list.size();

        if (list == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (size % 2 == 0) {
            list.remove(size / 2);
            list.remove((size / 2) - 1);
        } else if (size % 2 != 0) {
            list.remove((size / 2));
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my updated code:

```
public MyDequeue findMiddleNode() 
{
    DLNode first = getHeadNode();
    DLNode last = getTailNode();
    MyDequeue m = new MyDequeue();
    while(first!=last && first.getNext()!= last) 
    {
        first = first.getNext();
        last = last.getPrevious();
    }
    if(first == last) 
    {
        m.insertLast(first.getElement());           
        return m;
    }           
    else 
    {
        m.insertLast(first.getElement());
        m.insertLast(last.getElement());
        return m;
    }
}
```

the class MyDequeue is my implementation of a doubly linked list. the reason i returned MyDequeue is bcuz i already had a static print method that prints the elements of a doubly linked list. any suggestions for a better soln?